# Discriminant of $f(x^n)$ for $f$ a quadratic

Tags: polynomials

Let $f(x)=x^2-bx+c$, with $b,c$ in some field; let $\Delta = b^2-4c$ be the discriminant. I just did a lengthy calculation to find the discriminant of $f(x^n)$. If I did everything right, it's $n^2c^{n-1}\Delta^{2n}$.  Can you confirm or disconfirm this?

**Update:** correct answer is $n^{2n}c^{n-1}\Delta^n$; thank you David.

Comment: There is likely to be a short/nice way to approach it as product of difference of roots.

Comment: I get yours upto a constant term and $\Delta^n$.

Comment: @CalvinLin - that was the basis of my calculation. I could write it out?

Comment: I got $(-1)^n n^{2n}c^{n-1}\Delta^n$.  I probably made a mistake with the sign: if you remove the $(-1)^n$ this  checks with a few Maple calculations.  And in any case my formula obviously has the wrong sign when $n=1$.  But it was still a lengthy calculation ;-)

Comment: Ah.  I see where my mistakes are.  $n^{2n}c^{n-1}\Delta^n$ it is then. (If $\lambda,\lambda'$ are the roots of $f$, I was misreading $(\lambda-\lambda')^{2n}$ as $\Delta^{2n}$ when it's actually $\Delta^n$; and I was mis-simplifying $\prod_{j=0}^{n-1}\zeta^j\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(1-\zeta^k)$ as $\zeta^{\binom{n}{2}} n$ when it's actually $\zeta^{\binom{n}{2}}n^n$.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct answer is $n^{2n}c^{n-1}\Delta^n$; thank you David.