# Discriminant of $f(x^n)$

Tags: polynomials, discriminant

I read about this post: [Discriminant of $f(x^n)$ for $f$ a quadratic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/688033/discriminant-of-fxn-for-f-a-quadratic) about $\Delta f(x^n)=x^{2n}-bx^n+c$ if $f(x) = x^2-bx+c$ is a quadratic. In particular, $\Delta f(x^n) = n^{2n}c^{n-1}\Delta(f(x))$.

Is there any relation like this for general $f$?

Comment: It's usually a good idea to post a relevant equation, identity, or quantity directly in the question body rather than depending on an outside link that readers must follow and leave your question in order to read.  Can you expand the relevant discriminant information here?

Comment: @abiessu Got it, sorry, I've edited the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a relation like this for general $f$. To avoid leading term annoyances, every polynomial referenced in this answer will be monic -- if your $f$ is not monic, you can simply replace $f$ with $f$ divided by its leading coefficient and figure out the appropriate normalization to apply at the end.

For polynomials $f_1,\dots,f_n$,
$$\Delta(f_1\cdots f_n)=\prod_{i=1}^n\Delta(f_i)\prod_{1\leq i<j\leq n}\operatorname{Res}(f_i,f_j)^2,$$
where
$$\operatorname{Res}(f,g)=\prod_{f(\alpha)=0}g(\alpha)$$
is the [resultant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant) and the product is over roots $\alpha$ of $f$ counted with multiplicity. (This result comes directly from the definition of the discriminant as products of differences of roots.) One may compute, for $\beta,\gamma\in\mathbb C$,
$$\Delta(x^n-\beta)=\beta^{n-1}\Delta(x^n-1)=\beta^{n-1}(-1)^{n(n-1)/2+1}n^n$$
and
$$\operatorname{Res}(x^n-\beta,x^n-\gamma)=\prod_{x^n=\beta}(x^n-\gamma)=(\beta-\gamma)^n.$$
This means that, if $S$ is the multiset of roots of a polynomial $f$ (counted with multiplicity), then
\begin{align*}
\Delta(f(x^n))
&=\Delta\left(\prod_{\beta\in S}(x^n-\beta)\right)\\
&=\prod_{\beta\in S}\Delta(x^n-\beta)\prod_{\{\beta,\gamma\}\subset S}\operatorname{Res}(x^n-\beta,x^n-\gamma)^2\\
&=\prod_{\beta\in S}\left(n^n(-1)^{n(n-1)/2+1}\beta^{n-1}\right)\prod_{\{\beta,\gamma\}\subset S}(\beta-\gamma)^{2n}.
\end{align*}
The first term multiplies to
\begin{align*}
n^{n\deg f}(-1)^{\left(\frac{n(n-1)}2+1\right)\deg f}\left(\prod_{\beta\in S}\beta\right)^{n-1}
&=n^{n\deg f}(-1)^{\left(\frac{n(n-1)}2+1\right)\deg f}\left((-1)^{\deg f}f(0)\right)^{n-1}\\
&=n^{n\deg f}(-1)^{\left(\frac{n(n+1)}2\right)\deg f}f(0)^{n-1}.
\end{align*}
The second term is simply $\Delta(f)^n$. So,
$$\Delta\left(f(x^n)\right)=\left((-1)^{n(n+1)/2}n^n\right)^{\deg f}f(0)^{n-1}\Delta(f)^n.$$